# iOS - Singleton UIView? Facebook-style navigation

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, singleton

I'd like to implement something like the facebook navigation menu, where you click a menu button to slide the current view over to revel the menu underneath. The question is how to get the menu to always persist as the underlying view.

The menu has a tableView which will highlight the current view or section that you are in. Currently I have a property on each View that the menu will be assigned to, but I'm not sure how to set up a singleton UIView for the menu. In other words if the menu were not a singleton I could do this:

```
self.menu = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"menu" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

But in that case I'm creating a new menu for each view. I need to assign the SAME menu to each view.

Suggestions?

---

What about creating a singleton NSObject, which has the menu view as a property?

Then I could just grab this view from the singleton and assign it to self.menu of each view?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you will have some kind of main view controller handling all the different views that are required.

This view controller can have a property to store your "menu view"; when you create a new view controller for an item in your menu, you pass to it a reference to the "menu view" which is stored in the main view controller.

This could work for you without requiring the use of a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

There're numerous open-source controllers that imitate that behaviour (e.g. [this one](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ghsidebarnav), [this](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ecslidingviewcontroller--2) or [this](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mfsidemenu)) - you can check their implementation to get the idea of how they work (or use them in your project as they are)

Basically you need to create "main" view controller that handles both menu controller and your content controllers and navigation between them as @sergio said.

Comment: What if I need to target iOS 4.3? These all seem to use the container view controller that is only available for ios5+.

Comment: @soleil, try to look for another implementation. Or try to adopt those to iOS4 (you'll probably need to reimplement addChildViewController: and all functions to handle child controllers in container controller, but I'm not sure). And you also  always have an option to drop iOS4.3 support :)